# Displaying Office 2016 Add-in errors (for Visio)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-visio, dcom

I'm trying to display Office Add-in errors for Visio 2016.

A guide for earlier versions of Office ([here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619(v=vs.90).aspx), [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/library/bb608619(v=vs.100))) states:

> In the General section of the details pane, select Show add-in user
>   interface errors, and then click OK

From an Excel guide - because nothing specific to Visio can be found - ([here](http://www.spreadsheet1.com/show-add-in-user-interface-errors.html)), it supposedly can be enabled like so

[image: Excel]

However, in Visio 2016 there is no such setting.

I tried setting the “VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS” environment variable to 0 as in this guide ([here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/haahmadi/2010/05/26/my-office-addin-does-not-load/)), but still no COM add-in error alerts or messages appear.

Another guide ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14698249/1938889)) explains how to troubleshoot Add-in errors, but not display error alert messages.

How to display detailed Visio 2016 COM Add-in error messages similar to this one below?

[image: Add-in error message]

Comment: As far as I know there is no such feature in Visio. Visio was not originally a Microsoft product, it was bought in 2000 (or thereabouts) so has a different development history. It would be a useful feature though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such feature in Visio. Visio was not originally a Microsoft product, it was bought in 2000 (or thereabouts) so has a different development history. It would be a useful feature though.